# Spring project with DynamoDB; When updating the document with fewer attributes are these removed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have lost information in dynamoDB in the address attribute, I try to track when this information is lost, it is updated by different microservices, my question is that if I update a document (json) from a collection with fewer attributes, will these be lost? example,

insert {id:1,name:"gabriel", address:"xxx"}

update {id:1,name:"gabriel"}

when consulting the id 1 it would only have {id:1,name:"gabriel"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing you're using the Mapper Client for DynamoDB. Have a read of this blog, you need to set the right save behavior for your needs:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-the-savebehavior-configuration-for-the-dynamodbmapper/